# How to delete C:\ProgramData\Dell\SARemediation\SystemRepair

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

A little while ago, I had asked whether I could delete the aforementioned file. Apparently, I can, so I went ahead and tried. No matter what I did, however, I kept getting this notification even on Safe Mode:
[image]

How do I delete this file?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try removing (uninstalling) the Dell Support Assistant?  You probably need to remove this first and restart, then try again.

Comment: @John Yes, I did. Still there.

Comment: Try the suggestion offered by @Harrymc including using an Admin account and see if that works for you.  For troublesome files I know can be deleted without harm, I use Unlocker 1.92 (available on Major Geeks).

Comment: Use LockHunter, https://lockhunter.com/, or a similar tool. If it cannot delete it while Windows is running, it likely will do so after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This folder is used by some Dell apps that must have come preinstalled
on your computer. You must uninstall these apps before you may delete
this folder and its subfolders.

In addition, you need to do that using an Administrator user account.
From your photo, as an option was not offered to use such permissions,
it might be that your account is not Administrator.

Comment: No, my account is an admin account. What apps must I uninstall?

Comment: Start by the above suggested Dell Support Assistant, then continue with other Dell apps if required.

Answer (score 0):

you can take the ownership of this folder and its subfolders, then add privileges for your username and set full control.
Then you get access to this folder and you´ll see the content.
You might be able to delete the oldest files, but you can control the occupied capacity by Support Assist utility.
SA Remediation can sometimes make your C: drive full...